# PDO on GAE SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-platform

I have a GAE PHP application that use PDO for connecting a MySQL instance.
The MySQL instance is hosted in a different GCP project.
I have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Unable to find the socket transport \"unix\" - 
did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

this is the PDO code:

```
# GAE
$this->database = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>;dbname=<DB_NAME>', <USER>, <PASSWORD>);
$this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Is it possible connect a GAE PHP application to a MySQL instance of other project ?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed!!!
I had this code

```
$this->database = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>;dbname=<DB_NAME>', <USER>, <PASSWORD>);
```

and  was: `:/cloudsql/<PROJECT>:<REGION>:<DB_NAME>`

the solution is **remove colon**!!!

So this is the correct dsn:

```
$this->database = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<PROJECT>:<REGION>:<DB_NAME>;dbname=<DB_NAME>', <USER>, <PASSWORD>);
```